# F# class library code completion and highlighting does not work within C# program

Tags: f#, monodevelop, intellisense, c#-to-f#

I'm trying to figure out C#/F# interop and I'm running into roadblocks with code highlighting and completion in MonoDevelop v5.7.

F# library code in a separate project folder:

```
namespace FSharpLib

type FSharpClass() = 
    member this.MyProp = "Calling from F#!!!"
```

C# executable code in a separate project folder:

```cs
using System;
using FSharpLib;

namespace CallFromFSharp
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var y = new FSharpClass();
            Console.WriteLine (y.MyProp);
        }
    }
}
```

I've got the references working and the code compiles and runs fine, but code highlighting is showing errors:

> The name `FSharpClass' does not exist in this context

and code completion doesn't work.

I haven't tried with Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio (I'm on Linux), so I don't know if this is a problem with MonoDevelop or if I'm missing some way to write my F# code so that it works with all of the C# code highlighting & completion engines.

Comment: File a bug report in [MonoDevelop's BugZilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/describecomponents.cgi?product=MonoDevelop)?

Comment: This is a long standing issue which, it seems, has only been partially fixed: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues/156
It may be that MD drags behind XS, I don't know.